# Make <td> background-color equal array value, but each group of 3 have same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, conditional-statements

I have

```
for (var i = 0; itr < $("td").length; i++) {
    $("td").eq(i).css("background-color", Colors[i]);
}
```

Which works but it colors every individual td a new color and the row is 3 columns so I need every `<td>` in a row (3) have the same color. I cannot color the table row itself, so I need a work around by modifying the above code.

Comment: You want to color every row with a diferent color?

Comment: have you tried colgroup to color down a column?

Comment: I really rather a JS option rather than HTML

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
var Colors = ["red", "black", "purple", "blue", "gray", "green"];
for (var i = 0; i < $("tr").length; i++) {
    $("tr:eq(" + i + ")").children().css("background-color", Colors[i]);
} ​
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WhnSw/

But why can't you color the row? It is also easy:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("tr").length; i++) {
    $("tr:eq(" + i + ")").css("background-color", Colors[i]);
} ​
```

Comment: Just about to place that answer! +'d you :)

Comment: @Zuul, I know we have been thinking in the same direction, +'d your comment ;)

Comment: I should of mentioned I am using only td within a specific tr (defined by a class name) as in " tr.specific td " and using your code breaks my page for some reason. the page is data heavy and therefore contains several different table rows which are outside of what I am trying to edit. you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/WhnSw/1/

Comment: It works, but on my page it does not (stuff breaks), even though my first code doesnt break anything....is there any variation I can use perhaps? thank you so much for help

Comment: Could you provide a link to your page? It is hard to give a reason not observing your code.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot, you'd need to sign a NDA then, lol (it's a client)

Comment: Okay I got it to work, sorta, now I need to figure out other things. Thank you for help